# Vertically aligning <div> contents

Tags: css

The simplest things...  Why isn't the text in the  below centered vertically?  Isn't that what `vertical-align: middle` does?

```html
    <div style="width:100%;height: 300px;background-color: #0047b3;vertical-align: middle;">
      Why are you not centered vertically?!?!?!
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read some of the flex properties it gets lot easier see below
'

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0047b3;
  display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>whatever you want to align vertically centre </div>
```

Comment: I like this, but now the text isn't horizontally aligned, and using `text-align: center` doesn't seem to make it work.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @gtilflm try using `justify-content:center;`

Comment: nvm, I found `justify-content: center;` for those who are reading this comment.

Comment: lol... beat me by 1 sec. :)

Comment: yes if the text is concerned we can use  'justify-content: center';  But it's the best approach to align elements vertically center